# Webscraping problems returning a 404 error on google collab

Tags: python

I can't quite understand why this is returning a 404 error, would expect it to return a 200 error? I'm trying to scrape yahoo finance for stock prices.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                            
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/COKE'
r = requests.get(url)



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define headers in your requests object. Go with this:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```